# C++ how to check if file is in use - multi-threaded multi-process system

Tags: c++, multithreading, filesystems, multiprocess

C++:
Is there a way to check if a file has been opened for writing by another process/ class/ device ?

I am trying to read files from a folder that may be accessed by other processes for writing. If I read a file that is simultaneously being written on, both the read and the write process give me errors (the writing is incomplete, I might only get a header).
So I must check for some type of condition before I decide whether to open that specific file.
I have been using boost::filesystem to get my file list. I want compatibility with both Unix and Windows.

Comment: Please 'accept' one of the answers, which was most helpful to you. This shows, that this question is answered sufficiently and it's a little "Thank you" to the respondent. People prefer to answer questions from guys, who actually 'accept' answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a file *advisory lock*. In Unix, this is `flock`, in Windows it is `LockFile`.

However, the fact that your *reading* process is erroring probably indicates that you have not opened the file in read-only mode in that process. You must specify the correct flags for read-only access or from the OS' perspective you have two writers.

Both operating systems support reader-writer locks, where unlimited readers are allowed, but only in the absence of writers, and only at most one writer at a time will have access.

Since you say your system is multi-*process* (ie, not multi *thread*), you can't use a condition variable (unless it's in interprocess shared memory). You also can't use a single writer as a coordinator unless you're willing to shuttle your data there via sockets or shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about `boost::filesystem`, you're not going to get the granularity you need from that feature-set in order to perform the tasks you're requesting.  In general, there are two different approaches you can take:

1. Use a synchronization mechanism such as a named semaphore visible at the file-system level
2. Use file-locks (i.e., `fcntl` or `flock` on POSIX systems)

Unfortunately both approaches are going to be platform-specific, or at least specific to POSIX vs. Win32.

Answer (score 1):

A very nice solution can be found here using Sutter's active object https://sites.google.com/site/kjellhedstrom2/active-object-with-cpp0x

This is quite advanced but really scaled well on many cores.